# BigQuery failed to import Cloud Datastore backup file via Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

I was trying to load one of my data store table to BigQuery. When I found there is an option "AppEngine Datastore Backup" in the web ui of BigQuery, I'm very happy cause all my data are located in one data store table. It should be the easiest approach (I thought) to just export data via "Datastore Admin" page of Google App Engine and then import it in BigQuery.

The export process went quite smoothly and I happily watched all mapper tasks successfully finished. After this step, what I got are 255 files in one of my Cloud Storage bucket. The problem arose when I try to import it in the web-ui of BigQuery. I input the url of one of the 255 files as the source of data load. And all I got is following error message:

```
Errors:
Not Found: URI gs://your_backup_hscript/datastore_backup_queue_status_backup_2013_05_23_QueueStats-1581059100105C09ECD88-output-54-retry-0
```

I'm sure above URL is the right one cause I can download it with gsutil. And I can import one CSV file located in the same bucket. May I know your suggestion of next step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the reason now. I shall use the file with ".backup_info" suffix instead of arbitrary data file.

Cheers!

Comment: This got me started on the right path, I should also note that when exporting a single Entity there are two files. One with the ".backup_info" and one with ".{entity}.backup_info". You need the latter.

Comment: in managed cloud import export .backup_info file not generate. I am stucked. Help pleasee